# Variable value remains unchanged after running multiple queries in Node JS

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to check if a user with a given email id is registered previously. If it is, then a variable named `uniqueUser`, is set to `false`. However, this variable remains unchanged even when the condition is `true`. It's value changes locally, but once the promise is resolved, the value gets back to previous one.

Here are the codes :-

```
router.post('/register-user', multer_profile_pic.any(), (req, res, next) => {
   
    var uniqueUser = true; //----> This value is being focused
    const user = req.body;
   
    
    var query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1`;
  
    var values = [user.email];

   db.query(query,values)
            .then(result => {
                if(result.rowCount > 0) {
                    uniqueUser = false;
                    console.log("uniqueUser="+uniqueUser); //----> Here value becomes false
                   
                }
                
            })
            .catch(err => {
                
                uniqueUser=false;
            });
    
   
    if(uniqueUser) {
        console.log(uniqueUser); //----> Here value becomes true
      //INSERT QUERY HERE
    }
    
    const josn_resp = {
        response: response,
        message:message
    }
    res.json(josn_resp);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happened because you don't understand the promise event loop how work.

In your code `db.query(query,values)` and `if(uniqueUser) {` execute in same time in event loop and actually your variable `uniqueUser` never changed.

You should change your code like bellow:

```js
router.post('/register-user', multer_profile_pic.any(), (req, res, next) => {

  var uniqueUser = true; //----> This value is being focused
  const user = req.body;


  var query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1`;

  var values = [user.email];

  db.query(query, values)
    .then(result => {
      if (result.rowCount > 0) {
        uniqueUser = false;
        console.log('uniqueUser=' + uniqueUser); //----> Here value becomes false
      }

      if (uniqueUser) {
        console.log(uniqueUser); //----> Here value becomes true
        //INSERT QUERY HERE

        return db.query('insert-query');
      }

      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .then(() => {
      const josn_resp = {
        response: response,
        message: message,
      };

      res.json(josn_resp);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400);
      res.json({message: err.message})
    });
});
```

If you use nodeJs 12 and above I suggest use `async/await`:

```js
router.post('/register-user', multer_profile_pic.any(), async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = req.body;

  try {
    const result = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$1`, [user.email]);
    if (result.rowCount === 0) {
      await db.query('insert-query');
    }

    const josn_resp = {
      response: response,
      message: message,
    };

    res.json(josn_resp);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400);
    res.json({message: err.message})
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the documentation where this promise event loop is mentioned?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-event-loop-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-in-javascript